# bash securely pipe environment variable to stdin

Tags: bash, security, environment-variables

I have a password stored in an environment variable.

```bsh
read -s passwd
export passwd
```

#### Bad: Using `echo $passwd`

Now I want to pipe it to a command accepting the password through `stdin` (e.g., `kinit`). However, if bash has `set -x` enabled, then this will leak the password.

```bsh
(warning: will leak password if set -x is enabled)
$ echo $passwd | kinit x@example.com

+ kinit x@example.com
+ echo secretpassword
...(kinit output)...
```

#### Alternative: Using `printenv passwd`

So I used `printenv` to write the password to `stdin`, instead of `echo`.

```bsh
(is this ok?)
$ printenv passwd | kinit x@example.com

+ kinit x@example.com
+ printenv passwd
...(kinit output)...
```

This doesn't print the password to the bash output when I tried it.

#### Question: Is it OK to use `printenv`?

But is this actually secure? Is there a configuration of bash that could leak the password somewhere?

Edit: don't think `set -x` prints to stdout/stderr, fixed.

Comment: if it's an environmental variable anyone could just `echo $passwd` or run `env`

Comment: I'm more concerned with password leaking into files/logs/etc, not concerned with someone hijacking my shell session. This would be run in a CI/CD pipeline so I have some confidence that the build machine is not compromised.

Comment: I wanted to see if there are any more "gotchas" like `set -x` that make it bad to run a command with `printenv passwd`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `printenv`, the variable has to be exported, which means you're exposing it to other commands in the script, any of which could potentially leak it. But if there's no other command between exporting the variable and using it as input, and you unset it immediately after use, it would be unlikely to be dumped in the log accidentally.

If you're using bash, you could use a herestring instead:

```
kinit x@example.com <<<"$passwd"
```

Herestrings aren't included in `set -x` output, and the variable doesn't need to be exported:

```
$ bar=abc
+ bar=abc
$ cat <<<"$bar"
+ cat
abc
```

But herestrings create temporary files, so there's that to consider as a potential source of leakage.

Comment: To add more context about the temp files: "Here documents [and herestrings] create temporary files, but these files are deleted after opening and are not accessible to any other process." https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html.

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to comment this, but thank you for this answer!

Comment: In bash 5.1 (just released): "Here documents and here strings now use pipes for the expanded document if
   it's smaller than the pipe buffer size, reverting to temporary files if it's
   larger."

Comment: Some [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16045568/5339918) on this as I've never seen this type of heredoc. It expands the variable without needing to set start/end markers.

Answer (score 1):

I will give you an example with `sshpass` using a temporary fd  to use the password as an argument instead of stdin wit using `set -x` it won't printed out the password :

```
#Set the password as an environment variable
export password=MyPassword
#Create the file descriptor 3 and link it to /tmp/pwd, you can use one from 3 to 9.
exec 3<> /tmp/pwd
#Copy the content of password  env variable to /tmp/pwd using dd command
dd of=/tmp/pwd <<< "$password" 
#Here using cat and passing it to xargs so stdout will be catched by stdin of xargs, then the password will be available within the second  curly brackets
cat /tmp/pwd  | xargs -I {} sshpass -p {} ssh <user>@<ip>
#Close the file descriptor
exec 3>&-
#Remove the tmp file
rm -f /tmp/pwd
```

You can adjust this answer to your use cases.

Comment: could you add some comments to help explain what is going on in your script?

Comment: Thank you for this answer, have to say I don't fully understand all the bash contructs like `3<>` and `3>&-`. But just wondering, if `sshpass` fails and the script exits, won't the password remain stored in `/tmp/pwd`?

Comment: I have added some comments, here ssh will not be interactive so the commands after will be executed to remove the tmp file. it's just an example to use password as argument instead of stdin : `<command> -p <password>`

Comment: Thanks, I guess why not just pipe the herestring directly into the sshpass command?

Comment: Yes possible here, because if no parameter is submitted to sshpass then it will read from stdin then we can use herestring. But i insist that it can be helpfull with other commands like subscription-manager on redhat system that have an option `-p` to submit the password and subscription-manager does not have a mechanism to read drom stdin. hoping it's clear. thanks